How to convert a DokuWiki file with images to docx?
Here's what I'm trying and the output I get. It does create a docx file the correct text, but I can't figure out how to get it to pick up the images.
PS W:\pages\app\mobile\manual> pandoc -f dokuwiki -t docx --resource-path ../../../../media -o add-pickup.docx add-pickup.txt
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource /app/mobile/manual/addpickup-1.png: replacing image with description
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource /app/mobile/manual/addpickup-2.png: replacing image with description
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource /app/mobile/manual/addpickup-3.1.png: replacing image with description
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource /app/mobile/manual/addpickup-4.png: replacing image with description
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource /app/mobile/manual/addpickup-5.png: replacing image with description


Here is the directory structure I'm working with. The files are in pages/app/mobile/manual and the images are in media/app/mobile/manual. The whole wiki is in a mapped network drive that my computer has access to.
Root
- media
  - app
    - mobile
      - manual
- pages
  - app
    - mobile
      - manual

I achieved a partial solution by changing the image links in the wiki files from {{:app:mobile:manual:addpickup-1.png}} to {{:..:..:..:..:media:app:mobile:manual:addpickup-1.png}}, but then DokuWiki can't find the images.
Is there any way I can specify the --resource-path so that it'll work without changing the image links?
